# preg_replace regular expression issue

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, expression

I'm trying to clean up a string.

I need to only allow

1. Uppercase/lower letters
2. numbers
3. spaces, tabs, carriage returns
4. these characters: `_-+*()[]!#?.,;:'"<>`

Everything else needs to go bye-bye. How do I go about this? I have this, which works for the upper/lower case letters, numbers, and spaces. But I dont know how to account for the tabs, carriage returns, or how to do the special characters?

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 ]/i', '', $str);
```

Comment: Don’t ever hardcode `a-z` outside an RFC spec: it has a code smell. All letters are `\pL`, uppercase letters are `\p{Lu}`, and lowercase letter are `\p{Ll}`. There are also titlecase letters `\p{Lt}`, modifier letters `\p{Lm}`, and other letters `\p{Lo}`.  Note that there are also non-letter code points with the derived properties `\p{Alphabetic}`, `\p{Lowercase}`, and `\p{Uppercase}`.

Comment: I have no idea where to even go with this. Have any examples?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^\w\r\n\t+*()[\]!#?.\,;:\'"<> -]/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

\s - whitespace character (includes tabs and line breaks)
\r - carriage return
Use "\" character for special symobls.

Answer (score 1):

`$str = 'sample|';`


`$result = !(bool)strlen(preg_replace('/^[a-z0-9A-Z\r\s:_-+*()[]!#?.,;:\>\<]*/', '', $str))`